# EF Core: conditionally computed column

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

In my model I have AccountType property, which is mostly generated by database trigger, but sometimes can also be directly assigned:

```
public class Account
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute [DatabaseGenerated] allows me to automatically get database generated value back, whenever databaseContext.SaveChanges() executed.
However, this attribute seems to also prevent sending a value, if 
I wish to assign AccountType explicitly. What is the best way to implement such "partially" generated/computed column?

Comment: This seem to be what I'm looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties. But it didn't work, because ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate() is equivalent to the attribute in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this attribute seems to also prevent sending a value, if I wish to assign AccountType explicitly. What is the best way to implement such "partially" generated/computed column?

If you want to set a explicit value to a property decorected with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` ,  you need to drop down to the lower level metadata API and set `AfterSaveBehavior`/`BeforeSaveBehavior` like  below :

1. [IMutableProperty.BeforeSaveBehavior Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableproperty.beforesavebehavior?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableProperty_BeforeSaveBehavior) is used for Add state

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .Property(t => t.TestType)
            .Metadata.BeforeSaveBehavior=PropertySaveBehavior.Save;
   ```
2. [IMutableProperty.AfterSaveBehavior Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableproperty.aftersavebehavior?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableProperty_AfterSaveBehavior) is used for Update state

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
            .Property(t => t.TestType)
            .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior =PropertySaveBehavior.Save;
   ```

The [PropertySaveBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.propertysavebehavior?view=efcore-2.1) indicates how changes to the value of a property will be handled by Entity Framework change tracking which in turn will determine whether the value set is sent to the database or not.